# AngularJS Resolve Unknown keyProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, resolve

I am trying to resolve a JSON promise before loading a controller and template.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'index-ctrl-test.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl',
    resolve: {
        event: function ($http) {
            return $http.get('/api/eventInfo.json?event_name=Some Event Name');
        }
    }
  });
});

var IndexCtrl = app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', 'event', function ($scope,event)   {
  console.log(event.data);
}]);
```

The key of the resolve promise is injected into the controller, but it keeps throwing an error:

Error: Unknown provider: eventProvider <- event

The data does seem to be available, despite the error (i.e, console.log does in fact log the returned JSON object). Any ideas what is throwing the error? I'm not using a javascript minifier or obfuscator.

Comment: Show us your code for the eventProvider

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML view contain an `ng-controller="IndexCtrl"` attribute?
This instantiates the controller without injecting the `resolve` parameters, and would throw the error you see there.

If you remove that, and just use a plain `ng-view` instead, the controller will only be instantiated with the `$routeProvider` service, with the proper dependencies resolved.